# Get results from table based on values from another table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with the following columns

```
First_name, Last_name, Date_Of_Birth
```

How do I loop through another table to retrieve the results based on the values in the previous table?

For example, I would like all information in Table2 based ON A WHERE CLAUSE that matches the First_name, Last_name, Date_Of_Birth data from the rows in Table1

Thanks for reading

Comment: Hint: Use `INNER JOIN`

Comment: If its as simple as that I am going to go jump off a bridge... So...

SELECT Table1.First_name, Table1.Last_name, Table1.Date_Of_Birth, Table2.Comments
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.First_name = Table.First_name AND Table1.Last_name = Table2.Last_name AND Table1.Date_Of_Birth = Table2.Date_Of_Birth  ...???

Comment: @GMR You just have to be mindful that the combination of First, Last, and DOB uniquely identifies a record. For example, if you have two people named John Smith with 1/1/1990 DOB, then it can cause confusion. Generally, you want to join two tables on a primary key field or a field that you know will be unique.

Comment: @GMR, yes, that's pretty much it. Trial and error. And make sure it's a small bridge with deep water, no rocks. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use inner join for this. Inner joins compares the two tables to find pairs of rows that satisfy the join-predicate. Whenever the join predicate is satisfied by matching non-Null values, the matched pairs are included in the result set.I do not have the table names and number of attributes your table, so I have created a small example below where you can put in your values based on your table. For example:

SELECT First_name, Last_name, Date_Of_Birth, (Attributes_Of_Other_Table)

FROM

table.1

INNER JOIN

table.2 ON (t1.pattern = t2.pattern)

INNER JOIN

table.2 ON (t1.pattern = t2.pattern)

WHERE

(add in the where clause you want)

Comment: why are you Joining Table2 twice?

Comment: Just as an example to show INNER JOIN on multiple columns. As I do not know the contents of the table, I have just shown it there, or one is enough.

Comment: OP gives enough information for you to create an answer to show them what they need. I like your explanation. OP has 2 tables to join on 3 columns. Give them something they can use, so you can get votes for a well formulated answer.